# I want to add a form element in my route component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am new to react , I have this Route Component, inside this i'm creating my new

element for every row of my data but i also do want to add form so a user can create a new para. can anyone help me out please??

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';

class Comments extends Component {
state={
    Comment:[]
}
componentDidMount() {

    const { commentId }=this.props.location.state;
    axios.get(`./hn_data/${commentId}.json`)
        .then((res) => this.setState({ Comment: res.data }));
}

render() {

    console.log(this.state.Comment);

    return this.state.Comment.map(comment=>(
        <p>{comment.text}</p>
    ))
}
}

export default Comments;`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I got, you'd like to add a form for submitting new comments, write?

Try this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';

class Comments extends Component {
    state = {
        Comment: [],
        commentText: "",
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        const { commentId } = this.props.location.state;

        axios.get(`./hn_data/${commentId}.json`)
            .then((res) => this.setState({ Comment: res.data }));
    }

    postComment() {
        // add you comment to the database here
    }

    onCommentTextChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            commentText: event.currentTarget.value,
        });
    }

    renderComments() {
        return this.state.Comment.map(comment=>(
            <p>{comment.text}</p>
        ));
    }

    renderForm() {
        return (
            <div class="comment-form">
                <textarea
                    class="comment-form__text" 
                    value={this.state.newCommentText}
                    onChange={(event) => this.onCommentTextChange(event)}
                ></textarea>
                <button onClick={() => this.postComment()}>Submit</button>
            </div>
        )
    }

    render() {

        console.log(this.state.Comment);

        return (
            <div>
                {this.renderComments()}
                {this.renderForm()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Comments;
```

in postComment you can either add your this.state.commentText into state.Comment or post to backend.

Comment: Got It... Thank u .